# Discrete Fisher Information

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, fisher-information

I have a discrete data distribution: (1,1,2,2,1,1).
I wish to estimate its Fisher information. How should I proceed?
FI is normally inversely proportional to the variance of the data. The variance of the data comes out to be 0.267.

How should I compute FI according to the following equation?
$$ I(\theta) =  4 \sum_{i=1}^{n}{{(\sqrt{p_{i+1}}-\sqrt{p_i})}^2} $$

Answer (score 0):

Is your (1,1,2,2,1,1) vector giving observed counts over 6 distinct outcomes, or is it sequence of observations over 2 outcomes?

Either way, you can treat empirical distribution as a multinomial distribution with 1 draw, use observed counts to estimate parameters of that distribution, compute Fisher Information matrix using recipe here -- https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/578715/511

Comment: It is a vector giving observed counts over 6 distinct outcomes.

Comment: So your corresponding multinomial distribution has parameters $\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{8}$ and n=1 (number of trials), find Fisher Information matrix of that using the recipe and take trace

Comment: The FI for (1,1,2,2,1,1) and (1,1,2,1,2,1) will be the same?